# CSS position: sticky not working inside a wrapper element

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying CSS `position: sticky` property, it works in a simple parent and child structure. But, when I'm trying to implement it in a more complex parent and child `HTML` structure, it doesn't work as expected.

In example below, I want to make `<div class="ribbon">` as **sticky element** with a parent div as **sticky container** named `<div classs="element">`, and its grandparent named `<div class="viewport`"> acts as the `scrollable viewport`. It should `stick` on the `left: 0` whenever I scroll the viewport scrollbar, but it doesn't.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

html, body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container > .viewport {
    overflow: scroll;
}

.container > .viewport > .content {
    padding: 1em;
}

.container > .viewport > .content > .element {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.ribbon {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: bisque;
}

.ribbon .item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: .5em;
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.grid {
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 40em">
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="element">
                <div class="container ribbon" style="width: 50em">
                    <div class="viewport">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="item">Item 1</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 2</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 3</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 4</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 5</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 6</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 7</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 8</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 9</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 10</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 11</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 12</div>
                            <div class="item">Item 13</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>Grid content</h4>
                        <h4>Grid content</h4>
                        <h4>Grid content</h4>
                        <h4>Grid content</h4>
                        <h4>Grid content</h4>
                        <h4>Grid content</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: not yet, because they are different. `position: fixed` relates to `window` whereas `position: sticky` to another DOM element.

Comment: `position: sticky` is not work when you use `overflow` property

Comment: @VivekTarsariya so how can I make the `viewport` element become scrollable?